# Where on the data sheet is the supply current at 5 volts for the CD4081B?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I am trying to make use the CD4081B AND logic gate for starting basic Logic Gate circuits and I am trying to find the input current at 5 volts for the chip. I was wondering how to find it in the datasheet because I cannot. If anyone could help find it or show me how to calculate it myself that would be great.

Here is the link to the CD4081B datasheet:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4081b.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the current drawn by the chip in quiescent / static conditions then it is given in an alternative [datasheet by Fairchild](http://www.futurlec.com/4000Series/CD4081.shtml).

[image]

*Figure 1. Quiescent device current is very low. (1) The device current. (2) The input current.*

Generally the input resistance is so high that we ignore it. The situation changes when we feed it with a high frequency signal. The input capacitance can become a significant factor as it has to be charged and discharged.

[image]

*Figure 2. (3) Input capacitance.*

Comment: Does that mean that I can supply 5 volts and 1 Amp DC to the input of the chip and it will not harm the IC chip since the input resistance is so high?

Comment: What do you mean by "input"? The power pin or an input pin? Let me get you thinking: if I connect a 20 W light bulb to the 5 GW Irish national grid how much power do you think it will consume? (Hint: my house hasn't exploded in a fireball.) Now, if I connect a logic input pin that draws 0.3 µA to a 1 A supply how much current do you think it will draw? By the way, there's an [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) stack which is a better place for this type of question. Word your questions well though. We get a lot of bad questions that get closed.

Comment: Pin 14 on the CD4071B for the IC’s power which I believe is Vdd if I’m reading that right. So the supply voltage/current for pin 14.

Comment: Then it's $ I_{dd} $ as shown in (1).